# Gurobi Model search for variable with exact match (or exact match string search)

Tags: python, string, gurobi

Trying to use the following code to search for variables that have "732913342082_MAN-1"

```
[var for var in m.getVars() if '732913342082_MAN-1' in var.VarName]
```

but then it is giving me the following result:

```
[<gurobi.Var v1_Severn_732913342082_MAN-1>,
 <gurobi.Var v1_Severn_732913342082_MAN-10>,
 <gurobi.Var v5_27_732913342082_MAN-1>,
 <gurobi.Var v5_27_732913342082_MAN-10>,
 <gurobi.Var v0_Windsor Locks_732913342082_MAN-1>,
 <gurobi.Var v0_Windsor Locks_732913342082_MAN-10>,
 <gurobi.Var v2_Chesterfield_732913342082_MAN-1>,
 <gurobi.Var v2_Chesterfield_732913342082_MAN-10>,
 <gurobi.Var v6_Harrisburg_732913342082_MAN-10>,
 <gurobi.Var v6_Harrisburg_732913342082_MAN-1>]
```

And what I want is:

```
[<gurobi.Var v1_Severn_732913342082_MAN-1>,
 <gurobi.Var v5_27_732913342082_MAN-1>,
 <gurobi.Var v0_Windsor Locks_732913342082_MAN-1>,
 <gurobi.Var v2_Chesterfield_732913342082_MAN-1>,
 <gurobi.Var v6_Harrisburg_732913342082_MAN-1>]
```

Basically, it is giving me '732913342082_MAN-10' as well which I think is due to them looking alike.  I think this is more toward the exact string search part and hope someone can help!

Thanks!

Comment: The ">" is part of the variable structure and I just tried, it doesn't work...

Comment: Yeah I am looking into that way as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

Option 1: Use Python str.endswith():

```
[var for var in m.getVars() if var.VarName.endswith('732913342082_MAN-1')]`
```

Option 2: Create a regular expression:

```
import re
[var for var in m.getVars() if re.search('732913342082_MAN-1$', var.VarName)]
```

Option 3: Refactor your gurobipy code to use Model.addVars() to create a gurobipy.tupledict of Var objects, so that you can use [tupledict.select()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_tupledict.html) to get the subset you want:

```
x = m.addVars(index1, index2, index3, index4, ...)
# ...
x.select('*', '*', '732913342082', 'MAN-1')
```

For me, options 1 and 2 are quick-and-dirty; option 3 is cleaner and more efficient but may require some changes to your code.